# Unity whole scene disappears when zooming in

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine, zooming

My entire scene disappears as I zoom in. I can only view and edit the scene from a very far perspective. However, when playing the game everything is normal. This problem suddenly occured when I was trying things with the canvas (which I deleted afterwards).  What can I do?
I have already tried changing clipping plane settings on the main camera, and nothing changed.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Answer (score 8):

It went back to normal when I chose a sprite and pressed F key, highlighting it on the hierarchy.

Comment: but in my case you can't see the all objects at a time, that is painful when i adding new objects and need to position them perfectly

Comment: when i zoom at the new objects, old objects disappear

when i zoom at the new objects new objects disappear

how can i solve it

Answer (score 5):

You can selecet object you want and then press F. Then it focusses the screen on the object you selected. It will resolve the zooming error also.

Answer (score 1):

Double-Clicking any object in the scene also works.